# ViewBox diffrente interaction in uwp and wpf

Tags: wpf, viewbox, webview2

I want to make webview2 control have the same interaction in wpf and winui3, any body know how to do this?
I have the same code bellow:

```
<Grid Background="Red">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Viewbox Height="67" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Grid Height="120" Width="660">

            <controls:WebView2 x:Name="MyWebView"  
                               Source="https://lva.lenovo.com.cn/ad/ad.html" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>

</Grid>
```

the code  in winui3(uwp) project works fine, the webview2 content can scale to right size, but in wpf project, the webview2 content still keep the original size, don't scale.

the wpf sample code can be got from bellow link:
[wpf sample code](https://github.com/chenggj/viewbox-wpf-.git)

Bellow image is the difference of uwp and wpf.
[image]

Comment: The grid row is * height. Your viewbox is fixed height. You don't seem to have anything in row 0.  You realise rows and columns are zero indexed?

Comment: hi @Andy, thanks your reply, but I think it doesn't matter with the * height grid.  If I remove the rows and columns in root grid, it is the same result.

Comment: I found a property of WebView2 control is ZoomFactor, this property can scale my webview2 content to my container control. So I think my problem has been resolved, but I still want to know why it has different interaction in WPF and UWP.

Comment: @Nico Zhu Could you please take a look?